# Angular 2 , submenu need borderbottom only in one active sub menu

Tags: angular

i have borderbottom line in nav active button.
my link is ex. http://localhost:3000/#/dashboard/wage

with this code , i have active 2 buttons with bottomborder - dashboard and wage

css:

```
.sub-navbar li a:active {
color: white;
border-bottom: 4px solid #9ACD32;
background-color: #002b31;
```

}

```
<li *ngFor="let sub of nav.subMenu">
                    <a [routerLink]="'/dashboard'  + [sub.link]" [routerLinkActive]="['is-active']">
                        {{sub.name}}
                    </a>
                </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I thinks it's as simple as you styling the `a element` with a class called 'active': `a:active`. But your router link is setting a class called `is-active`. Try setting it to `active`.

```
<a [routerLink]="'/dashboard'  + [sub.link]" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
```

Comment: nah.. we need to get only child link and to do active,  not +dashboard